# Распаковка массива zip архивов в одну папку с переименованием файлов

Tags: windows, файлы, cmd, powershell, zip

Есть папка с большим количеством zip-архивов.
Каждый архив содержит внутри папку(имя папки то же, что и у архива) с 1+ файлов.
Как c помощью средств windows(и какого-нибудь архиватора)извлечь все файлы в одну папку так, чтобы конечные файлы были переименованы по шаблону "<имя папки>-<имя файла>"?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут только скрипт писать свой надо

Comment: `FOR %%Z IN ("%src_dir%\*.zip") DO (
      7z e "%%Z" -o"%tgt_dir%"
    )`  а вот по поводу переименования - не знаю..

Answer (score 6):

Kак подсказал [@nick_gabpe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190232/nick-gabpe), нужно распаковать в папку:

```
FOR %%Z IN ("%src_dir%\*.zip") DO ( 7z e "%%Z" -o"%tgt_dir%" )
```

Далее `PowerShell` скрипт выполнит остальное:

```
$fiels = Get-ChildItem -Path . -rec -Filter "*.txt" # найти все файлы из директории, откуда запускается (.), с расширением txt 
foreach($f in $fiels){
    $dirName = (Get-Item $f.FullName).Directory.Name # получаем имя папки
    # копируем файл с новым именем. Путь C:\temp\1111 должен существовать 
    Copy-Item -Path $f.FullName -Destination "C:\temp\1111\$($dirName+ "-" + $f.Name)" 
}
```

Comment: Ну зачем приплетать PowerShell?

Comment: из-за метки powershell на вопросе

Comment: Ой.. Тогда сорри :)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на чистом PowerShell (без использования внешних утилит):

```
# Указываем папку с архивами
$rootPath = 'D:\TEST'

# Извлекаем и удаляем все архивы
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Get-Item "$rootPath\*.zip" | ForEach-Object {
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($_.FullName, $rootPath)
    Remove-Item $_.FullName -Verbose
}

# Избавляемся от папок
Get-ChildItem $rootPath -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | ForEach-Object {
        Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination "$($_.Directory.Parent.FullName)\$($_.Directory.BaseName)-$($_.Name)" -Verbose
    }
    Remove-Item $_.FullName -Verbose
}
```